# keep getting error "command not found: javac-algs4"

Tags: java, algorithm, java-17

Following the Algorithm I class, I just left all the files and jar inside the same “hello” folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHEoV.png)
However, when running the  "javac-algs4 CollidingDisks.java" command code, keep getting the error "zsh: command not found: javac-algs4";
Do I need to move the algs4.jar folder outside the “hello" folder?

Comment: It's difficult to see from that picture what the structure of your files is. Please execute the following command and paste the result as text formatted as code into the question. Change into the directory that contains the 'hello' directory first:  `find -type f -name \*.java`

Comment: You want `javac  -classpath  algs4.jar  YourSourceFile.java`. You can abbreviate `-classpath` to `-cp` but either way it is a _separate_ word on the command line, separated by spaces as shown, not run together like `javac-algs4`. A jar file is actually a file, even though your IDE and maybe Windows tools make it look like a 'folder'.

Comment: thank u for the answer. I used "javac  -classpath  algs4.jar  CollidingDisks.java" to compile the file, and it's working, CollidingDisks.class was generated by this command. However, when I use the "java  -classpath  algs4.jar  CollidingDisks" command to execute, keep getting" Could not find or load main class CollidingDisks".

Comment: *...keep getting" Could not find or load main class CollidingDisks* That's probably a package error (which is why I asked for your console output for `find`)

Comment: I got the answer. I have to run  ava -cp ".:./algs4.jar" CollidingDisks to make it works. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: OK. Then you have no (the default) package

Answer (score 0):

At least for git bash (for windows) I was able to fix these commands.

Wrappers were located in `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\` but was placed here with .sh extension. So first you need to remove extension from them.

Then, looking into their code, you'll see they're looking into `LIFT_LIB="/usr/local/lift/lib"` folder for an algs4.jar file, and the folder was here but empty. So I placed algs4.jar file here.

After that `algs4-javac` and `algs4-java` wrappers started working from git-bash terminal in IntelliJ.

Comment: *...but was placed here with .sh extension...* There are usually scripts for each platform. That's for Unixes. You need the one for Windows. You are also quoting from a script that is not for Windows

Comment: @g00se idk.. It's installed as part of the whole IntelliJ package for Algorithms. Everything except these git bash terminal special wrapper commands for java is ok.